# Pass href to jquery

Tags: jquery

I use the following code to open external pages within a div on the current page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#content").load("content.html");
});

(function($) {  
$(function() {  
$('.load_link').click(function() {  
     $("#content").load($(this).attr('href'));  
     var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
     $row.removeClass("rownotselected").addClass("rowselected");
     $row.siblings("tr").removeClass("rowselected").addClass("rownotselected");
     return false;  
 });
```

Then for the actual link:

```
<a href="content2.html" class="load_link">Link text</a>
```

The links are displayed in a table and I like to be able to make the whole row clickable to open the link rather than just the text. Previosuly I only had one page to load so I hard coded the page name in the function and just opened it whenever the row was clicked with the following code:

```
<tr class="rownotselected load_link" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

However now there are multiple rows that need to be clickable which point to different pages, so I need to be able to pass the href value to the function via the above method in the same way as I do for a regular link. Is this possible?

I hope I've made the question clear, please do let me know if not.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245627/trigger-jquery-by-clicking-on-table-row ?

Comment: @Niklas It's the same code, but a slightly different question, I think...

Comment: Sorry, yes it is a different question and I didn't want to get the answers confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, using the [`has` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector):

```
$('tr:has(.load_link)') // select tr elements that have .load_link descendants
    .click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var link = $(this).find('a.load_link');

        $('#content').load(link.attr('href'));
        $(this).removeClass('rownotselected').addClass('rowselected')
               .siblings()
                   .removeClass("rowselected").addClass("rownotselected");
    });
```

See the API:

- [`has` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector)
- [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault)
- [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find)

Comment: Wouldn't `$('tr.load_link')` instead of `$('tr:has(.load_link)')` be better here, as his markup showed that the class was part of the `<tr>` element as well?

Comment: @Niklas I read that as "I used to have `load_link` on the `tr`, now I've put it on the `a`". I agree that the question is vague, and your point may be valid.